# Uncaught TypeError: formData is not iterable

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to collect and create an object from different child components using hooks.

There are multiple child components which will update a state in the parent and create a main object to send it to API.

```
// creating a hook

const [formData, setFormData] = useState({});


// Getting data from the child and setting it using a hook set method

const deliveryContactDetails = deliveryData => {  
    contacts.push(deliveryData);
};

const productNameData = productData => {
    setFormData(...formData, productData);
}

const onboardDetailsData = detailsData => {
    setFormData(...formData, detailsData)
}


// Using ref to call the child and send data to parent

 useImperativeHandle(ref,() => ({
    sendData() {
        productRef.current.sendData()
        detailsRef.current.sendData()
        deliveryRef.current.map(
          ref => ref.current.sendData()
        );
        setFormData(...formData, { contacts: contactArray });
        props.saveItem(tempObj);
    }
  }));
```

Getting the error in the console

> corporateOnboardingDetails.js:137 Uncaught TypeError: formData is not iterable at Object.productNameData [as saveProduct] (corporateOnboardingDetails.js:137)

Comment: `formData` is initialized as `{}`, i.e not an iterable object (i.e not an array)

Comment: Use useState ([])

Comment: what is the state structure you want to achieve?

Comment: @JosephD.

{
a: 'hello',
b: 'hi',
c: 'wassup',
d: [{a: '1'},{a:'2'}]
e: 'done'
}

Answer (score 1):

You tried to spread your object as arguments to a function call. You need to pass an object to `setFormData` function (you forgot about brackets `{}`).

```
const productNameData = productData => {
    setFormData({...formData, productData});
}

const onboardDetailsData = detailsData => {
    setFormData({...formData, detailsData});
}
```